# automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent doesn't do anything

Tags: ios, core-data

I was watching a WWDC 2016 (What's new in Core Data) video about some "new" changes and at some point it's said that this new property `automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent` is supposed to automatically merge the changes from the parent on the child context.

I created a simple test case:

```
CustomObject *customObject = [[CustomObject alloc] initWithContext:self.persistentContainer.viewContext];
customObject.name = @"TEST";
customObject.customID = 2252;
self.persistentContainer.viewContext.mergePolicy = NSMergeByPropertyObjectTrumpMergePolicy;

NSManagedObjectContext *firstContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSMainQueueConcurrencyType];
firstContext.parentContext = self.persistentContainer.viewContext;
firstContext.mergePolicy = NSMergeByPropertyObjectTrumpMergePolicy;
firstContext.automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent = YES;

CustomObject *contextObj = [firstContext objectWithID:customObject.objectID];
NSLog(@"NAME [%@]", contextObj.name);
customObject.name = @"JO";
[self.persistentContainer.viewContext save:NULL];
NSLog(@"NAME [%@]", contextObj.name);
```

The output is:

```
 NAME [TEST]
 NAME [TEST]
```

I was hoping it would be:

```
NAME [TEST]
NAME [JO]
```

if I use a `[firstContext refreshAllObjects];` it will work as I expect, but it makes not difference if `automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent` is set to YES or NO.

Am I missing something on how this is supposed to work? The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsmanagedobjectcontext/1845237-automaticallymergeschangesfrompa) doesn't help much.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You are fetching and updating object in firstContext. To verify `automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent`, you should fetch it from `self.persistentContainer.viewContext` and update.

```
self.secondObject = [[SecondCustomObject alloc] initWithContext:self.persistentContainer.viewContext];
self.secondObject.name = @"TEST";
self.persistentContainer.viewContext.mergePolicy = NSMergeByPropertyObjectTrumpMergePolicy;



NSManagedObjectContext *firstContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSMainQueueConcurrencyType];
firstContext.parentContext = self.persistentContainer.viewContext;
firstContext.mergePolicy = NSMergeByPropertyObjectTrumpMergePolicy;
firstContext.automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent = YES;
//firstContext.stalenessInterval = 0;

SecondCustomObject *contextObj = [self.persistentContainer.viewContext objectWithID:self.secondObject.objectID];
NSLog(@"NAME [%@]", contextObj.name);
contextObj.name = @"JO";
[self.persistentContainer.viewContext save:NULL];
SecondCustomObject * contextObj1 = [firstContext objectWithID:self.secondObject.objectID];
NSLog(@"NAME [%@]", contextObj.name);
NSLog(@"NAME [%@]", contextObj1.name);


 NAME [TEST]
 NAME [JO]
 NAME [JO]
```

Answer (score 1):

When you set `automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent = YES;` and then make save in your parent context CoreData automatically calls `mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:` on your child context by dispatching this block on the child queue (by calling `performBlock:` as usual). 
As soon as both your contexts work on the main queue you'll see changes only on the next main loop

Try

```
CustomObject *contextObj = [firstContext objectWithID:customObject.objectID];
NSLog(@"NAME [%@]", contextObj.name);
customObject.name = @"JO";
[self.persistentContainer.viewContext save:NULL];
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
   NSLog(@"NAME [%@]", contextObj.name);
});
```